# How to access the pk for a category_count title in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a category widget that uses a view function to count the number of posts under a certain category and list the titles and the count. I have the title as a link and want to link to my category detail page but since its just a title and not the actual category object I can't seem to figure out what to put in the href in the html.

Model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Category"
    verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
    ordering = ['title']

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

View:

```
def get_category_count():
queryset = Post \
    .objects \
    .values('categories__title') \
    .annotate(Count('categories__title'))
return queryset
```

HTML:

```html
{% for cat in category_count %}
  <div class="item d-flex justify-content-between">
    <a href="????????????????" class="ntd">
      {{ cat.categories__title }}
    </a>
    <span>{{ cat.categories__title__count }}</span>
  </div>
  <hr/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please properly format code, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should query in the opposite direction:

```
from django.db.models import Count

def get_category_count():
    return Category.objects.annotate(post_count=Count('post'))
```

Now the `Category` objects contain an extra attribute `.post_count` that contains the number of related counts. You thus can render with `{{ cat.title }}`, and obtain the primary key with `cat.pk`:

```
{% for cat in category_count %}
    <div class="item d-flex justify-content-between">
        <a href="something with {{ cat.pk }}" class="ntd">{{ cat.title }}</a>
        <span>{{ cat.title }}</span>
    </div>
    <hr/>
{% endfor %}
```

You of course will need to write the href itself, since you did not provide any `url`/`path` that you want to use. You probably better use the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to "calculate" the href.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I'm obviously still learning and I appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: changed the second cat.title to cat.post_count and got the count next to the titles and the links work with url 'category_detail' pk=cat.pk